# Which implementation is better (DRY and KISS)

Tags: java, dry, design-principles

Below I have methods to return month name. In first one implementation I use switch/case, this method is longer and validation is in the last line. On second one I make validation in first line and instead of switch/case I declared table with months name.

Which one is better when I think about KISS and DRY principles?

```
public String getMonthName(int month) {
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            return "January";
        case 2:
            return "February";
        case 3:
            return "March";
        case 4:
            return "April";
        case 5:
            return "May";
        case 6:
            return "June";
        case 7:
            return "July";
        case 8:
            return "August";
        case 9:
            return "September";
        case 10:
            return "October";
        case 11:
            return "November";
        case 12:
            return "December";
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("month must be in range 1 to 12");
    }
}
```

Or maybe this one?

```
public String getMonthNameNew(int month) {
    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("month must be in range 1 to 12");
    String[] months = {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
    };
    return months[month - 1];
}
```

Comment: Imo, second one - I would go in direction of limiting the returns from the method.

Comment: You could also just use an `Enum` to capture the same case in less code

Comment: @Mike Tung is completely correct, and your second one whenever used creates new unused instance everytime, so it is more inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the second one easier to read. It's shorter and with a precondition check which immediately tells you what values are allowed. In the first example you have to go through the entire method body to understand that.

Saying all the above the method should be written using [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) as:

```
public String getMonthNameNew(int month) {
  return Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because of using the existing `Month` enum in the JDK

Answer (score 0):

For a theoretical example, both would do (I would slightly prefer the first one, as that shows the "mapping" of numbers to strings within one line.  Option 2 requires you to understand what `months[month - 1];` will do for you. As suggested in the comments, the "most straight forward" solution would be framed around a Month [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and making that month name a field of that enum for example.

In the real world, both examples are simply insufficient.

Here you would focus on "dont repeat yourself" and look into an existing library class to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

With cases like this, it's good to make a list of pro/cons.

Example 1:
Pro:

- Easy to understand
- Readable

Con:

- Hard to extend (How would you return the name of month in different languages?).
- Other Java APIs use month values 0 to 11.
- Almost twice as long as the second example.

Example 2:
Pro:

- Compact
- If you change the code slightly, you can fill the array from different sources (properties files, databases).
- Flexible

Con:

- Clever. The code depends on the fact that there are no gaps in the data set. While this is true in this case, it might not be as clear cut in others.
- Other Java APIs use month values 0 to 11 (same as above).

Without additional requirements, I don't see a clear winner here.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments you can just do an enumeration class to do it.

```
public enum Months {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
}
```